# Solving a Riemann sum

Tags: calculus

How can I isolate the "i" inside the sigma?
I keep getting stuck with the "i" over the "n", so I can never pull all the "n"s out.

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sum _{i=1}^n \frac{n}{i^2+n^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$\frac {n}{i^2+n^2}=\frac {1}{n}\frac {1}{(\frac {i}{n})^2+1} $$

$$=\frac {b-a}{n}\frac {1}{(a+i\frac {b-a}{n})^2+1} $$

with $a=0,b=1$.

Comment: thanks! but as i said in the question im exactly stuck in that part.

Comment: @L.Santos : It's not altogether clear which part you're having difficulty with. If there's any way for you to edit the question to be clearer about that, that would help.

Comment: why do i have to change it into an integral? I did alot of riemann sums and this is the only one that i have to change into an integral. why ?